# Cannot activate Bluetooth on Toshiba Netbook, missing or corrupt tosbtAPI.dll?

Tags: bluetooth, toshiba-laptop

I cannot activate my bluetooth connection in my netbook. 
An error comes up like missing or corrupt 'tosbtapi.dll'. How to handles this problem? 
Many site offering the tosbtapi.dll, but I dont trust them.

I am already scan and repair using CCleaner and Glary Utilities but still it doesnt work.

The Netbook is running Windows 7 Starter

Comment: Which OS do you use? What's your exact Netbook model? Have you tried reinstalling the Bluetooth drivers?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 Starter. I forget about the Netbook model. I'll inform you later... I'm not using my netbook today. Actually, I already update the bluetooth driver (Properties | Update Drivers...)

Comment: Did the drivers get updated? If not, I recommend re-downloading the BT driver package from the netbook manufacturer's site and see if you can manually reinstall. Also try running `sfc /scannow` from an [elevated command prompt](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/windows-elevated-command-prompt).

Comment: It said driver already updated, but it still error. I already download the BT driver package for Toshiba from here (http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Remote-Utils/Toshiba-Bluetooth-Stack.shtml). I'll try reinstall later.

Comment: Is that the latest version? Check Toshiba's site and especially your netbook's driver list for the latest version of the driver package. Did you also try sfc?

Comment: sfc /scannow? Not yet. I'll try it later from elevated command prompt.

Comment: sfc /scannow, checked. Reinstalling from thoshiba site, checked. But still, doesnt work.